# How to use "basic" as connection type?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm able to use Oracle SQLDeveloper to make a connection to an Oracle database. I'm using "basic" as connection type and I can access database successfully. The problem is that basic authentication is the only way to access that database at the moment (there is some misconfigururation but this is another problem and can not be solved by myself).

To work around this I want to use basic authentication with JDBC. Is this possible? Can someone give me an example? I found only examples with thin or oci configuration. Both are not working for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. What do you meant by -  I'm using "basic" as connection .." and "problem is that basic authentication".

Comment: "basic as authentication" means: In SQLDeveloper you have these options in field "connection type": BASIC, TNS, LDAP, Advanced, Local / Bequeath. Basic is the standard option in that tool. I can insert parameters like hostname, port, sid/service name. The result is a working connection and my connection string look like this un/pw@hostname:port/sid. I use the same string with JDBC (and also in sqlplus) and execute it on the same machine, but it's not working...

Comment: "problem is that basic authentication is the only way to access" means: Other options (TNS, LDAP, Advanced, Local / Bequeath) are not working at the moment because of some configuration problems on db server.

Comment: You have to add a fragment of related code in your post.

Comment: Thx for your answer AVC. :) This is my sqlplus call: 

sqlplus un/pw@//host:port:sid
 
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Dec 10 10:18:26 2011
 
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I can also send my jdbc code if it's helpful, but it's the sames error message and I think it's the same problem.

Comment: I could understand that message if SQLDeveloper won't work, too.

Comment: SQL Developer has an option for JDBC connection type, IIRC. Why not use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no mistake in configuration. But there was a problem with the cluster (cluster switched to the other node). I can't understand this behaviour and I can't reproduce it anymore, but it's working again now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the help in SQL Developer:

---

> Advanced connection type
>
> Custom JDBC URL: URL for connecting directly from Java to the
>   database; overrides any other connection type specification. If you
>   are using TNS or a naming service with the OCI driver, you must
>   specify this information: Example: 
>   ***jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/@localhost:1521:orcl***
>
> Note that in this example, the "/" is required, and the user will be
>   prompted to enter the password. *I actually wasn't prompted for p/s see notes below*
>
> To use a custom JDBC URL, the system on which SQL Developer is running
>   must have an Oracle Client installation that contains the JDBC and
>   orai18n libraries, is present on the path, and is version 10.2 or
>   later.

So all you need to do is select the "Advanced" connection Type, then input the below line (changed to your settings)

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/@HOST:PORT:SID
```

but it will also work (and use the Username/Password already inputted) if you omit the "User/" as such

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID
```

---

It seems to use the password that is already in the "Password" box in the Database Connection.

If this does not work for you, post how it does not work.  I tried the connections from "Basic", TNSNames, and Advanced (using the THIN client) without incident- take note of the using a custom JDBC URL, but I would have to ask why if that is the intent?

hth